# How to use system ("R CMD SHLIB TWoLife.cpp") with relative pathway here ()

Tags: r

My lab has this code that uses R to call for a c++ function.

The begining  usually reads:

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS" = "-fopenmp -DPARALLEL")
system("rm code.so")
system("rm code.o")
system("rm code.dll")
system ("R CMD SHLIB code.cpp")
```

Im tryng to turn this into a package and therefore trying to use relative pathways such as below. To no avail.

```
system (paste("R CMD SHLIB -I",here::here("FolderA","FolderB",'code.cpp'),sep=""))
```

How was it supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You really really really should consider turning this into a (simple enough) package.  There are lots of tutorial, pick one or two and have a go at it.

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare. It should never be used.

Comment: `here::here` only works *within R projects*, which are a vaguely defined concept. It might not be appropriate for you — consult the documentation. Beyond that, your question needs more details to be answerable.

Comment: I removed your [[tag:cmd]] tag, because, in your submitted code `CMD` is a `R` option for command, (in this case `SHLIB`), not the Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`.